# How to solve 3 variable in 2 equation?

Tags: contest-math, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

This paper is abstracted from 2007 British Mathematics Olympiad Round 1 Question 2.

I am currently practicing grade 8 (Singapore Secondary 2) for the upcoming Singapore Mathematics Olympiad(SMO). Even before solving the question,is it even possible to solve 3 variable of 2 equation?(As from the title of the question).

Question:

> Find all solutions in positive integers $x,y,z$ to the simultaneous equations.
>
> $x+y-z=12$
>
> $x^2+y^2-z^2=12$

Of course the first thing that I almost done is $x+y-z=x^2+y^2-z^2$ which is definitely not the way.

I cannot use elimination method as in the end there will be 2 variable in an equation.

I tried using substitution method like $x=12-y+z$,so,$(12-y+z)^2+y^2-z^2=12$ and substituting $x^2=12-y^2+z^2$ where $x=\sqrt {12-y^2+z^2}$,so,$\sqrt {12-y+z}+y-z=12$

Therefore,I get these equations.

- $(12-y+z)^2+y^2-z^2=12$
- $\sqrt {12-y+z}+y-z=12$

If I expand,these equation ended up

- $z^2-yz+y\sqrt {12-y^2+z^2}-z\sqrt {12-y^2+z^2}=78$ (Squared version) OR $\sqrt {12-y^2+z^2}+y-z=12$ (Non-Squared Version)
- $y^2-12y+12z-yz=-66$

From here I don't see how to eliminate one variable away.I am sure what I am doing is wrong or expanded wrongly.Any other ways to do this question?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$$x+y-12=z \Rightarrow x^2+y^2-(x+y-12)^2=12$$

This leads to 
$$xy-12x-12y+78=0$$
or
$$(x-12)(y-12)=66$$

Now check all the possible ways of writing $66$ as a product of 2 integers.

Comment: That simple?Wow.I didn't have to think that complicated

Answer (score 0):

@ministic2001,  You had the right idea   $y^2-12y+12z-yz=-66$ can be rewritten as followed:
 $$(y-z)(y-12)=-66 $$ 
According to Euclid's lemma, $(y-12)$ must divide -66.
Hence,
$$(y-12)=\pm 1 $$
$$(y-12)=\pm 2 $$
$$(y-12)=\pm 3 $$
$$(y-12)=\pm 6 $$
$$(y-12)=\pm 11 $$
$$(y-12)=\pm 22 $$
$$(y-12)=\pm 33 $$
$$(y-12)=\pm 66 $$
From that you can easily find $z$ as followed:
$$z=\dfrac{66}{(y-12)}+y$$
As for $x$, the easiest way to obtain it is from:
$$x=12-(y-z)$$